# mysql automatic slave configuration to choose from either of 2 master

Tags: mysql

Was wondering if there is way for having automtic switch over of master for slave when one of the masters fails.eg : 2 master m1,m2 (m2 is semi-sync slave of m1).slave s1 has 2 choices of replication first it would try m1,if timeouted after certain time or any other reason,change replication to m2.so i need to specify both m1 (priority 1),m2 (priority 2) in some configuration for change over.I dont want slaves to be promoted to master as i already have master m2 as my backup for this purpose.Could i do like the above setup ?

Prem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of tools have tried to do this.  One popular tool is [MMM](http://mysql-mmm.org/).  But MMM suffers from some unfortunate [bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mysql-mmm/+bug/771843).  For example, if m1 fails, the replica(s) resubscribe to m2, but without any way of knowing if they're subscribing to the correct binlog position!  No one seems to be fixing MMM at this point.  The MySQL community is looking for a replacement tool that works better.

There are other solutions from third-party vendors to support true multi-master replication in a cluster:

- Codership [MySQL/Galera](http://www.codership.com/products/mysql_galera)
- Continuent [Tungsten Replicator](http://www.continuent.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=348&Itemid=88)

There are also other high-availability solutions that provide redundancy, but they come with their own operational complexity and some limitations.

- [Using MySQL with DRBD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ha-drbd.html)
- [MySQL Cluster NDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster.html)

Comment: thanx Bill.i did look at tungsten replicator but dint find an automatic master failover handling and restoration procedure for corrupted master after switching over. when i researched i found a tool master high availability for automatci master failover handling http://code.google.com/p/mysql-master-ha/